# Нужно найти все теги без класса с помощью регуляки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо сформулировать регулярное выражение для поиска тегов `<img ...>`, но только тех, в которых еще нет классов.

```
<div class="item">
   <img src="1.jpg" alt="1">
</div>
<div class="item">
   <img src="2.jpg" class="blablabla" alt="2">
</div>
<div class="item">
   <img src="3.jpg" alt="3">
</div>
```

По сути нужно найти 1 и 3 варианты, чтобы в дальнейшем прописать класс. На сайте 700+ страниц и в ручную - не вариант. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: 1. Зачем вам нужно проставлять эти классы? 2. в каком виде хранится содержимое этих 700+ страниц?

Comment: перводим 7 сайтовс bs3 на bs5. Хранится все в sql на 120мб+. Пишем скрипт на питоне. Разбираться в селекторах многие из которых уже устарели нет желания. проще автоматизировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var s = `<div class="item">
   <img src="1.jpg" alt="1">
</div>
<div class="item">
   <img src="2.jpg" class="blablabla" alt="2">
</div>
<div class="item">
   <img src="3.jpg" alt="3">
</div>`

console.log(s.match(/<img\b((?!\bclass\b)[^>])*>/g))
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием *negative lookahead* `(?!...)`

```
\<img\b(?![^\>]*\bclass=)
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OdnrnM/1)

Comment: `<img(?![^>]*\sclass=)(?:\s[^>]*)?>` [будет правильнее](https://regex101.com/r/OdnrnM/2).